# Symfony Vendor Bundle error paramFetcher with FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, bundle, fosrestbundle, vendor

I'm trying make vendor's bundle which one using FOSRestBundle.

I need to use paramFetcher, but in browser I see:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "fos_rest" (in xxx/vendor/company/bundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "fos_rest", found none
```

I made config.yml in this vendor bundle and loading it by
`DependencyInjection/Configuration`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps, you miss configuration of fosRestBundle. Look at config.yml if you find fost_rest key.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html#configuration

Comment: Are you sure? My vendor bundle don't see FOSRest I think. Error message: "There is no extension able to load the configuration for "fos_rest" "

Comment: It would be good to post your `config.yml` file for reference.

Comment: @AlvinBunk my config.yml in vendor bundle is very simple:

config.yml:
fos_rest
     param_fetcher_listener: true

Comment: DO YOU WANT HELP? Please post the `fos_rest` config section so we know what you have configured!

Comment: @AlvinBunk i pasted it above. 
It's so simple to not make a mistake. My config: https://pastebin.com/CnAX2YEh

Comment: Do you have `new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle()` added to your `app/AppKernel.php` file?